# SupportMapFragment - Binary xml file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a main class which extends FragmentActivty and CustomMapFragment which extends SupportMapFragment, i see this errors at logCat when I call this my customMapFragment into the FragmentActivity.

LogCat Result :

```
01-05 17:43:13.916: D/ERROR(2371): Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
01-05 17:43:13.936: W/System.err(2371): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 2: Error inflating class fragment
01-05 17:43:13.936: W/System.err(2371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-05 17:43:13.946: W/System.err(2371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
01-05 17:43:13.958: W/System.err(2371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-05 17:43:13.958: W/System.err(2371):     at com.main.whereismyfriend.CustomMapFragment .onCreateView(CustomMapFragment .java:48)
01-05 17:43:13.958: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-05 17:43:13.958: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-05 17:43:13.966: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-05 17:43:13.966: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-05 17:43:13.966: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
01-05 17:43:13.976: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-05 17:43:14.006: W/System.err(2371):     at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-05 17:43:14.006: W/System.err(2371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 17:43:14.016: W/System.err(2371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 17:43:14.035: W/System.err(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-05 17:43:14.035: W/System.err(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 17:43:14.056: W/System.err(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-05 17:43:14.066: W/System.err(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-05 17:43:14.075: W/System.err(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-05 17:43:14.075: W/System.err(2371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 17:43:14.096: W/System.err(2371): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f050011, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-05 17:43:14.156: W/System.err(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
01-05 17:43:14.166: W/System.err(2371):     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-05 17:43:14.166: W/System.err(2371):     ... 18 more
01-05 17:43:14.186: D/AndroidRuntime(2371): Shutting down VM
01-05 17:43:14.186: W/dalvikvm(2371): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at com.main.whereismyfriend.CustomMapFragment .onResume(CustomMapFragment .java:96)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1521)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-05 17:43:14.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ...

    CustomMapFragment fragment = new CustomMapFragment (getApplicationContext(),this);
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment ).commit();

           ...      
}
```

CustomMapFragment :

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener  {

private LocationClient locationClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private GoogleMap map;
FragmentActivity activity;
private Context context;
View view;

public CustomMapFragment (Context context,FragmentActivity activity){
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container,false);


        SupportMapFragment suppFragManager = (SupportMapFragment)activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = suppFragManager.getMap();

        locationClient = new LocationClient(context,this,this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(9000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(900);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        return view;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

...
```

map_layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<permission
    android:name="com.main.whereismyfriend.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.main.whereismyfriend.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***" />

    ...

 </application>
```

NOTE : I use android.support.v4 lib at this classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
```

So, `CustomMapFragment` is a `SupportMapFragment`...

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container,false);
```

...into which you are trying to inflate *another* `SupportMapFragment`.

This will not work well.

*Either* have `CustomMapFragment` extend `SupportMapFragment` (and delete its `onCreateView()` plus `map_layout.xml`) *or* use your `map_layout.xml`. Do not do both.

Answer (score 0):

In your case everything is perfect just check if you added two keys in manifest file

> If everything is woking same as google code then please check manifest file in my case i added geo key and map key that's why exception occurs,

**Note - do not add two keys in manifest file remove map key**

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

above code and add this code.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/auto_location"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```